# How to get access to any property or field using expression

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, expression

I want to get value from property or field by name using expression.
Is it possible?

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Value {get;set;} = "testvalue";
}
// like this
var delegate = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, string, string>>(/* some parameters*/ ).Compile();
var myClass = new MyClass();
var result = delegate.Invoke(myClass, "Value");
// result == "testvalue"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use expressions here? This question seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. But I just find a faster way to member access and actually want to find all ways for it. Maybe this question cannot be solved but I want to know it